# How to verify the data type of Json response field in rest assured

Tags: automated-tests, rest-assured, assertion, rest-assured-jsonpath, assertj

How can we verify the Json data type of mentioned fields such as "price", "ck", "name", "enabled" and "tags" in rest assured test.

```json
    {
      "odd": {
        "price": 200,
        "ck": 12.2,
        "name": "test this",
        "enabled": true,
        "tags": null
      }
    }
```

Is there any way or any assertion library which provide data type verification as mentioned in rest assured test example where instead of asserting the actual value of given key we can verify only the data type as mentioned in below example.

```
ValidatableResponse response =
            
given().
    spec(requestSpec).
    headers("authkey", "abcdxxxxxxxxxyz").
    pathParam("uid", oddUid).
when().
    get("/orders" + "/{uid}").
then().
    assertThat().
    statusCode(200).
    body(
           "odd.price",  isNumber(),
           "odd.name", isString(),
           "enabled", isboolean()
           "tags", isNull()
         );
```

Comment: Did you try schema validation? https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#json-schema-validation

Comment: My goal is to assert the key's data type in above example

Answer (score 3):

If we want to validate our response in `.body()` method, then we can use Rest-Assured build-in matchers using `Matchers` class:

```java
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.isA;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.nullValue;

...

given().
    spec(requestSpec).
    headers("authkey", "abcdxxxxxxxxxyz").
    pathParam("uid", oddUid).
when().
    get("/orders" + "/{uid}").
then().
    body("odd.price", isA(Integer.class)).
    body("odd.name",  isA(String.class)).
    body("enabled",   isA(Boolean.class)).
    body("tags",      nullValue()).
```

OR we can use some assertion library, e.g. AssertJ:

```java
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

...

JsonPath response = given().
    spec(requestSpec).
    headers("authkey", "abcdxxxxxxxxxyz").
    pathParam("uid", oddUid).
when().
    get("/orders" + "/{uid}").
then().
extract().jsonPath();

assertThat(jsonPath.get("odd.price") instanceof Integer).isTrue();
```

Comment: @swapnilshirke You're welcome! Can you also check my answer as correct one :)